# Changing a ToolTip's cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, tooltip

How can I set the default cursor shown when hovering over a ToolTip? I've already created a custom ToolTip class to adjust the color/font, so if necessary I can make changes there.

The ToolTip is shown from a panel in a windows form. The panel's cursor property is set to Cursors.Hand and I would like the ToolTip to match. I've tried changing the form-level cursor in the panel's MouseEnter event, but it's only semi-functional. It quickly alternates between Cursors.Default and Cursors.Hand when I move the cursor around over the ToolTip (as if the tip is forcing the default cursor).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On iconPanel's MouseEnter:

```
Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
if(!showingTip) {
    showingTip = true;
    changeIconTip.Show("Choose image...", iconPanel, 2, 2, 4000);        
}
```

On iconPanel's MouseLeave:

```
Rectangle iconPanelArea = new Rectangle(iconPanel.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), iconPanel.Size);
Point c = Cursor.Position;
if(!iconPanelArea.Contains(c)) {
    showingTip = false;
    changeIconTip.Hide(iconPanel);
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Note: On MouseLeave when the cursor hovers over the ToolTip, technically it 'leaves' the iconPanel (even though it's still inside of the panel's bounds). The Contains check only sets the cursor back to the default if it visually leaves the panel.

Comment: Can you post some code for your custom tooltip?  Normally when you move the mouse the tooltip disappears.

Comment: I can still give you a snippit if you'd like, but I used the standard ToolTip class instead with the same result. It does disappear after a 4 second duration I specified, but it's during those seconds that I'm getting the unwanted behavior. Editing my original post now to include some code...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the cursor alternating.  On Windows 8.1, the cursor stays the hand when the mouse is over the tooltip.  Try this code:

```
public class Form3 : Form {

    Panel iconPanel = new Panel() { BackColor = Color.RosyBrown, Size = new Size(200, 200) };
    ToolTip changeIconTip = new ToolTip();
    bool showingTip = false;

    public Form3() {
        Controls.Add(iconPanel);

        iconPanel.MouseEnter += iconPanel_MouseEnter;
        iconPanel.MouseLeave += iconPanel_MouseLeave;
    }

    void iconPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Rectangle iconPanelArea = new Rectangle(iconPanel.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)), iconPanel.Size);
        Point c = Cursor.Position;
        if (!iconPanelArea.Contains(c)) {
            showingTip = false;
            changeIconTip.Hide(iconPanel);
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }

    void iconPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        if (!showingTip) {
            showingTip = true;
            changeIconTip.Show("Choose image...", iconPanel, 2, 2, 4000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it's still doing it for me with the given code... I hadn't considered it, but maybe it's an issue relating to bootcamp display drivers. I'll test it out on my pc when I get home.

Comment: I tested frameworks 2.0 to 4.5 and they all worked fine.  I also searched for mouseleave over tooltip and didn't find anything useful.  I don't think a tooltip window can capture the mouse input, so it shouldn't trigger a mouse leave.